# Is there a way to avoid being backfilled onto an ongoing match?

Tags: rocket-league

I hate being backfilled onto losing games. It is really disheartening to queue up for a match, enter in game, only to find that I'm placed on the losing team down 5 goals with only 1 minute left in the match.

I searched throughout the options menu and can't seem to find anything to disable backfill. Is this something I can customize at all, or will I always be forced to put up with losing matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is unfortunately no way to stop from being backfilled in casuals. The only option is to play ranked, or to keep requeuing.